# search for business that carry my products on google maps by zipcode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My requirement is as follows,

say my business  product is available for sale in many stores. When user goes to find location of these stores  who  carry my product,

1) based on user Ip address the location should be detected (nice to have)

2) provide zip code field and let filter by distance (10mi,25mi,50mi).
fetch all business locations that carry my products by the provided zipcode.

3) I show results on map and also in following format
Costco , 10 Lawrance Exoressway, Sunnyvale CA, Hours, phone number, website
Safeway, 1500 almaden Expressway, San Jose CA, Hours, phone number, website
wholefoods , blossomhill rd, Losgatos CA, Hours, phone number, website

Any information or examples will be really appreciated Thanks

Comment: You will need to know what businesses carry your product and add markers to a map based on proximity to a customer's lat/lng.

Comment: There currently isn't a capability in Google Maps to allow you to search for "places that sell doritos" or whatever your product is.